# Calculate average return from time series with stock prices

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Time series with datetime and price and it represents a historical data for a company stock price. The problem is that the date for example one year ago could be Saturday or Sunday... or Christmas. It would not return me any value.

This is what I'm trying to:

```
stockRate.price_1month = objects.First(x => x.date>= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1)).price;
stockRate.price_1year = objects.First(x => x.date>= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)).price;
stockRate.price_2year = objects.First(x => x.date>= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2)).price;
stockRate.price_3year = objects.First(x => x.date>= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3)).price;
```

If there is no value in the series for the datetime one year ago, fetch the value before that in the series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are taking the first, but you haven't specified in what order they should be in, so unless they come in the exact order you need, you should specify it.  I've also reversed your logic based on your explanation with the understanding that "before that" means an earlier date.

```
stockRate.price_1month=objects
  .OrderByDescending(x=>x.date)
  .First(x=>x.date<=DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1))
  .price;
```